# String value being stored inside array by MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to store a string values in MongoDB, here is the C# code that I'm currently using:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("_id", "pk-0");
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Push("address", "MyStreet 1");
    update  = update.AddToSet("Address 2", "MyStreet 2");
await Collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

Weirdly, both `AddToSet()` and `Push()` methods creates an array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAnIx.png) with a string value inside it instead of just a string, see the screenshot below from my Admin UI that shows the result from my code.

[image]

Any idea of how I can get my code to store the string directly without putting it inside an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Push` and `AddToSeat` are array operators. If you need to store a scalar value you need to use `Set`:

```
var update = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.Set("address", "MyStreet 1");
```

[Documentation for .Net driver](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/definitions/).